# Accidentally sent BCH instead of BTC to a BTC address (Block chain)

Tags: blockchain, coinbase.com, cross-chain-recovery

I've accidentally sent BCH from Coinbase to a BTC address of Block chain. Both accounts belong to me. Is there any way to recover it? Please help me.

Comment: Blockchain.com is custodial, right? I think you have to email them asking for them to recover it, if you don't hold the private keys there is nothing you can do.

Comment: I did. Gave them the required details. Is there any chance my funds would be recovered?

Comment: yes, but it's up to them. Probably they will charge you a fee for recovering those funds and if it's too small, they will probably ignore it. Offer them part of the funds in return for the effort, maybe that will increase your odds

Comment: Sure. Thanks! It's around 600$.